# Does disabling javascript in browsers affect jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know user disabled the JavaScript in his browser, it leads to disabled the JavaScript validations on client side. Whether it may affect the jQuery validations or not and I need to know conceptual explain.

Comment: jQuery *IS* JavaScript. Disabling JavaScript will kill jQuery, too, yes.

Comment: jQuery is a library written in javascript, is should affect it.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. So Yes!

Comment: If I don't have any power to my appartment, will my electric toaster still work?

Comment: Guys, why do you down-vote this question? All of us were beginners a while ago.

Comment: This is a legitimate newbie question. For most people the answer is obvious, but for some it is not. Stack Overflow is for people at all levels of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, jQuery is a Javascript library, so if Javascript is switched off in the browser, then jQuery will not run.